# How to persist Netbeans output window for ease of re-executing

Tags: java, netbeans

I notice that when I run a file or do a Maven build Netbeans will re-use the same output window tab.  That is to say it will overwrite the output tab that was just used for the previous run/build to display the new run/build output.

Often times I do a build then go to one of my Java files and run it.  I would like for the build output tab to remain so that I could just hit the "re-run" button on the build output window.  The best example I can come up with is Windows' pin to start feature.  Essentially I would like to take my build output tab and pin it so that it persists vs getting overwritten with the output of the next runs.

thanks

Comment: Try double-click on the title bar of the Output tab, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

`Tools` -> `Options` -> `Java` -> `Maven`

and uncheck `Reuse Output Tabs from Finished Processes`

From the documentation :

> **Reuse Output Tabs from Finished Processes**
>
> When selected, Maven output messages are displayed in the same tab in
>   the Output window. When deselected, a new tab is opened for each new
>   Maven process.

[image]